# Is this an unknown pattern in prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

I am trying to figure out if the pattern I've found concerning twin primes is a known pattern or not. It turns out that with every set of twin primes, if the **higher** of the two numbers is converted to radix 7, and then the individual digits of the number are added together and continually added together until a 1 or 2 digit number is leftover, the number is always equal to **6 mod +1**.

The **lower** of the two numbers is always **6 mod -1** with same calculation.

Examples:

**Lower twin (radix 10)/ Lower twin (radix 7)/ [sum of digits to 2 digits]/ MOD 6**

```
<ul>59 / 113 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>71 / 131 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>101 / 203 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>107 / 212 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>137 / 254 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>149 / 302 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>179 / 344 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>191 / 362 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>197 / 401 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>227 / 443 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>239 / 461 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>269 / 533 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>281 / 551 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>311 / 623 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>347 / 1004 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>419 / 1136 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>431 / 1154 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>461 / 1226 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>521 / 1343 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>569 / 1442 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>599 / 1514 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>617 / 1541 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>641 / 1604 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>659 / 1631 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>809 / 2234 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>821 / 2252 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>827 / 2261 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>857 / 2333 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>881 / 2366 / 17 / 5</ul>
<ul>1019 / 2654 / 17 / 5</ul>
<ul>1031 / 3002 / 5 / 5</ul>
<ul>1049 / 3026 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1061 / 3044 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1091 / 3116 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1151 / 3233 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1229 / 3404 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1277 / 3503 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1289 / 3521 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1301 / 3536 / 17 / 5</ul>
<ul>1319 / 3563 / 17 / 5</ul>
<ul>1427 / 4106 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1451 / 4142 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1481 / 4214 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1487 / 4223 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>1607 / 4454 / 17 / 5</ul>
<ul>1619 / 4502 / 11 / 5</ul>
<ul>963426767 / 32605664252 / 41 / 5</ul>
<ul>963427259 / 32605665554 / 47 / 5</ul>
<ul>963427301 / 32605665644 / 47 / 5</ul>
<ul>963427559 / 32605666463 / 47 / 5</ul>
<ul>963427919 / 32606000516 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963428021 / 32606001023 / 23 / 5</ul>
<ul>963428099 / 32606001164 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963428561 / 32606002424 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963428861 / 32606003333 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963428957 / 32606003531 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963429167 / 32606004251 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963430019 / 32606006606 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963430079 / 32606010023 / 23 / 5</ul>
<ul>963430289 / 32606010443 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963431177 / 32606013152 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963431321 / 32606013446 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963431477 / 32606014061 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963431717 / 32606014553 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963432131 / 32606016014 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963432917 / 32606021216 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963432989 / 32606021351 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963433319 / 32606022332 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963433439 / 32606022563 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963433697 / 32606023412 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963434411 / 32606025452 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963434579 / 32606026112 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963434609 / 32606026154 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963434891 / 32606030036 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963435227 / 32606031026 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963435491 / 32606031554 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963436037 / 32606033264 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963436601 / 32606035031 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963437261 / 32606036663 / 41 / 5</ul>
<ul>963437399 / 32606040251 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963437927 / 32606041634 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963437939 / 32606041652 / 35 / 5</ul>
<ul>963438017 / 32606042123 / 29 / 5</ul>
<ul>963438041 / 32606042156 / 35 / 5</ul>
```

**Higher twin (radix 10)/ Higher twin (radix 7)/ [sum of digits to 2 digits]/ MOD 6**

```
<ul>571 / 1444 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>601 / 1516 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>619 / 1543 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>643 / 1606 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>661 / 1633 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>811 / 2236 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>823 / 2254 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>829 / 2263 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>859 / 2335 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>883 / 2401 / 7 / 1</ul>
<ul>1021 / 2656 / 19 / 1</ul>
<ul>1033 / 3004 / 7 / 1</ul>
<ul>1051 / 3031 / 7 / 1</ul>
<ul>1063 / 3046 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1093 / 3121 / 7 / 1</ul>
<ul>1153 / 3235 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1231 / 3406 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1279 / 3505 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1291 / 3523 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1303 / 3541 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1321 / 3565 / 19 / 1</ul>
<ul>1429 / 4111 / 7 / 1</ul>
<ul>1453 / 4144 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>1483 / 4216 / 13 / 1</ul>
<ul>961750903 / 32555514331 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961751209 / 32555515246 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961752301 / 32555521366 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961752349 / 32555521465 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961752553 / 32555522206 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961753789 / 32555525623 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961753831 / 32555526013 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961754011 / 32555526361 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961754071 / 32555526505 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961754461 / 32555530603 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961755019 / 32555532331 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961757059 / 32555541304 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961757311 / 32555542114 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961757431 / 32555542345 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961757683 / 32555543155 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961758673 / 32555546101 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961759111 / 32555550265 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961759483 / 32555551336 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961759831 / 32555552344 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961759861 / 32555552416 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961760119 / 32555553235 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961760719 / 32555555053 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961761013 / 32555555653 / 49 / 1</ul>
<ul>961761139 / 32555556223 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961761343 / 32555556634 / 49 / 1</ul>
<ul>961761403 / 32555560051 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961761571 / 32555560411 / 37 / 1</ul>
<ul>961762033 / 32555561641 / 43 / 1</ul>
<ul>961762591 / 32555563366 / 49 / 1</ul>
```

I have other questions related to prime numbers but first want to see how valid or known this part is before I continue. I am not a mathematician.

Comment: I think all you are saying here is that if $p$ and $p+2$ are primes then $p\equiv-1\pmod 6$. That is easy to prove (with the exception of $p=3$).

Comment: Thanks, I see now that it isn't very novel. In radix 6, all the lower twins would automatically have an ending digit of 5 and the higher twins an ending digit of 1.

Comment: Note that $+1 \mod 6$ and $-1 \mod 6$ are the accepted notations for what you mean by $6 \mod +1$ and $6 \mod -1$, respectively.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : That's not all he's saying; there's also a point about multiplication in modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Code-Guru : You can write $+1\bmod6$ in MathJax without those huge horizontal spaces, by using \bmod instead of \mod. The "b" stands for "binary" and it means the spacing should be that which is used for binary operation symbols. That large space is for occasions like this: $$ (52 \equiv 64) \mod 6, $$ which means $52$ and $64$ both leave the same remainder when divided by $6. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the tip. I didn't like the way my comment rendered, but did not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
d_0 + 7d_1 + 7^2 d_2 + 7^3 d_3 + \cdots & \equiv d_0 + 1d_1 + 1^2 d_2 + 1^3 d_3+\cdots & &\mod 6 \\[10pt]
& \equiv d_0 + d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + \cdots & & \mod 6
\end{align}

What is at work here is something that says if $a\equiv A\bmod 6$ and $b\equiv B\bmod 6$ then $ab\equiv AB\bmod6$. Proving that takes a bit of elementary algebra. Applying it here we have $7\equiv 1;$ therefore $7\times7\equiv 1\times 1,$ etc.

The fact that twin primes are always of the form $6n\pm1,$ plus the facts above lead to the conclusion that the pattern you've identified will persist.